# How do I correctly power the l298n motor driver with 6v?

Tags: batteries, dc-motor, raspberry-pi, l298

Recently, I have purchased the L298N Motor Driver with a couple of 3V-6V motors. I am planning to make a robot buggy to hold other projects I may do with the Raspberry Pi. Currently, I have been unable to figure out how to properly power the motors and the driver at the same time. For now, I have taped four AA batteries together to test the motors on with the driver. On my version of the L298N, the power inputs include 12V and 5V. After scouring the internet for hours, I have not been able to figure out exactly what to do with my dual-motor setup. For now, both of the jumpers on ENA and ENB have been attached. I tried connecting the 12V **input** on the driver to the temporary AA batteries, but the red power LED on the driver didn't turn on. The red LED would turn on though when I supplied 5V through the 5V punch block. That had not powered the motors sufficiently. What is the proper way to do this?
Here is a schematic of the wiring I have set up.
Keep in mind the pins that the wires are connected to on the Raspberry Pi are random (Couldn't "pin" them down correctly)
[image: Schematic from Fritzing]

Comment: It would be helpful if you supplied us with a schematic of what you plan to do and with a datasheet of the used components.

Comment: _" I tried connecting the 12V input on the driver to the temporary AA batteries, but all it does was get the wire a little bit hot,"_ - It should not make the wires at all hot. Are you sure the battery polarity was correct?

Comment: Yes, the problem might have been that I was physically touching them together. I tried doing the same thing recently without touching them together, and there were no signs of power on the board (red LED)

Comment: On the image, you are connecting battery negative to GPIO3, which you probably wanted to connect to ground.

Comment: Yes, I know. I should have added "The pins on the Pi are all wrong". Fritzing has this glitch where the pin tips disappear when holding a wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 batteries add up to 6V, apparently this board requires 9 to 12 volts power supply. Try throwing a couple more batteries in series or get a 9V battery instead.

The 5V next to the power supply input is an output which you can use to power your raspberry, but make sure to not mess up the ground as you have in the picture you've shown. Ground is physical pin 6 on the raspberry, not 5.

If you really insist on powering it with a 6V supply, then get a boost converter.

Comment: Thanks! The motors max out at 6v together though, but this answer will work for me and for anyone else with my question.

Comment: @tussiez200 I'm not sure I understand what you mean by motors maxing out at 6v together but you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 12V on the battery?
Pin 9 of the L298N should be 4.5V to 7V for the logic.
Pin 4 is the 6V for it to power the motors.
Connect the +6V to pin 4 and pin 9 and the ground of the 6V is 0V for pin 8. Pin 1 and pin 15 should also be connected to 0V.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for an answer:
You cannot expect the motors to be powered by connecting 5V to the driver board.
You need to connect 5V for the logic FIRST, then connect the motor power on the second power block.
Here is some proof:
[image: Image of schematic from L298N]

The image is from the Arduino forums where someone had the same problem as me [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=445630.0).
By the way, you *cannot* power the L298 motor driver module with 6V. The minimum required for it to work properly is 7.5V.